# Why can't I see my transactions on Blockchain.com?

Tags: coinbase.com, blockexplorer

I've a Bitcoin address on which I made a couple of transactions. From what I understand of the blockchain, the ledger is public and anyone can list the transactions linked to a particular address.

If so, why do I see zero transaction when keying my address `39QUZnHVbtXGreq3zndkPtrg1TSho2Mbht` on [https://www.blockchain.com](https://www.blockchain.com/en/btc/address/39QUZnHVbtXGreq3zndkPtrg1TSho2Mbht) ?

Same for [https://blockexplorer.com](https://blockexplorer.com/address/39QUZnHVbtXGreq3zndkPtrg1TSho2Mbht).

Comment: Are you sure the transactions were confirmed? If they don't get mined, they won't be included in a block. Also, how do you know this address has been used to make transactions?

Comment: I've made a transfer two days ago from an address stored on my computer with Electrum to this Coinbase address. Both Electrum and Coinbase show the transfer as confirmed and balances are updated.

Comment: it would make sense if this was the address you think you sent the coinbase funds _from_, because there is no guarantee which internal address coinbase decides to send coins from.

Comment: Are you sure that you sent BTC, and not some altcoin?

Comment: @chytrik yes I confirm it's BTC

Comment: Do you have a transaction-ID - what do the explorers say about the transaction?

Comment: By entering the details of the [transaction on Blockchain.com](https://www.blockchain.com/fr/btc/tx/90d5c44aedd8434bf1b579451d754273913190add6f733edaf3e27b5c302eee8) I can see some info. The origin address is not the one I manage in Electrum and the destination address is not the one I see on Coinbase (it also seems that [the BTC address on Coinbase regularly changes](https://support.coinbase.com/customer/en/portal/articles/2276500-why-did-my-wallet-address-change-), confirming @JBaczuk's assumption).
Furthermore, why are there two destination addresses displayed on Blockchain.com ?

Comment: Have a read about change outputs and hd wallets

Answer (score 1):

My assumption would be that this is due to the way coinbase handles deposits. 
You can tell more of the story by grabbing the transaction details from their website.

Click on the transaction in the Accounts section and look for the "View transaction" link and it will take you to it.

[image]